# How to run script from environment in Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have got recommendations to run Python script on Linux Server using this sequence:

1) source *path to  environment*

2) python *path to python script*

So, I need to call this script from `php` command `system`:

Should it be like this?

```
system("source *path to  environment* python *path to python script*")
```

How to set environment and then run script?

Comment: Those two commands need to be separated. Should it be `source *path to  environment* && python *path to python script*` or something like that?

Comment: I don't know really how to use that, so I have installed environment from which  run script

Comment: An python environement is used to encapsulate a python interpreter and its libraries. By doing that, you ensure to always use the libraries you installed in this environement and not polluting another python install on your system, especially if you have python2 and 3. In your case, make sure your env is installed and configured. Doing `source path_env` won't work if you don't have the env configured.

Answer (score 1):

```
system("*path/to/environment*/bin/python *path to python script*")
```

is enough. The trick is to run the script using python from the environment; that way you don't need to `source` the activation script.

Comment: Do you mean something this: `~/myenv/bin/python /home/o/o/j/public_html/library/excel/excel.py`?

Comment: Yep, exactly. When you run python from the environment it automatically access libraries installed in the environment so you don't need to activate the environment using `source`.

Answer (score -1):

Your python script need to contain 'shebang' string at the top **#!/usr/bin/env python**

for example file **start.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def some_func():
    print("Run some python function")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_func()
```

then also you need to make it executable with command:

```
chmod +x start.py
```

and you can run it:

```
./start.py
```

Comment: Nothing of it is necessary. `python script` executes the script without a shebang and executable attribute. And you've completely forgotten about virtual environment (`source activate`).