# Running automatically 2 python files not coded on the same environment

Tags: python, windows, version, libraries, environment

I have 2 codes which are not running on the same python version (more precisely not the same lib versions).
I tried to run one of them on more recent versions but it won't work since it's not my code and I can't really update it myself.

I need the output of the first as an input of the second one.

So I was wondering if there was a way to run files on 2 different environment automatically.

PS: I'm on Windows

Comment: Did you try to output the results into a file and load them in the second script?

Comment: I could do that but I actually need to make everything automatic

Comment: how do the scripts "talk" right now? How does the output from one get to the other?

Comment: It'd be an image, the first one write it and the second one use it

Comment: well then what's the problem. Run the first one, and then the second one?

Comment: As I said they're not working on the same environment, which mean if I want to do it I need to do it manually, but I want everything to be automatic
What would be a command line to run a python file on a specific env

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693571/how-to-run-script-from-environment-in-python

Answer (score 1):

> need the output of the first as an input of the second one.

```
$ chmod +x file A
```

create a file to store output:

```
$ touch file_a_output.txt
```

execute fileA and redirect its output to the .txt file

```
$ echo ./fileA.py > file_a_output.txt
```

file_a_output.txt will store the output of file A and you can use that output as file B's input.

If you are going to repeat this many times then you can create a bash script with the same commands and execute that.

edit: (assuming fileA's output is text)